# How can I have different states of expansion in LuaTex/LuaLaTex for debugging for instance?

Tags: debugging, lua, state, expansion

I am preparing LaTex/Tex fragments with lua programs getting information from SQL request to a database (LuaSQL).
I wish I could see intermediate states of expansion for debugging purpose but also to control what has been brought from SQL requests and lua processings.
My dream would be for instance to see the code of my Latex page as if I had typed it myself manually with all the information given by the SQL requests and the lua processing.
I would then have a first processing with my lua programs and SQL request to build a valid and readable luaLatex code I could amend if necessary ; then I would compile again that file to obtain the wanted pdf document.

Today, I use a lua development environment, ZeroBrane Studio, to execute and test the lua chunk before I integrate it in my luaLatex code. For instance:
my lua chunk :

```
for k,v in pairs(data.param) do
  print('\\def\\'..k..'{'..data.param[k]..'}')
end
```

lua print out:

```
\gdef\pB{0.7}
\gdef\pAinterB{0.5}
\gdef\pA{0.4}
\gdef\pAuB{0.6}
```

luaLaTex code :

```
nothing visible ! except that now I can use \pA for instance in the code
```

my dream would be to have, in the luaLatex code :

```
\gdef\pB{0.7}
\gdef\pAinterB{0.5}
\gdef\pA{0.4}
\gdef\pAuB{0.6}
```

May be a solution would stand in the use of the expl3 extension ? But since I am not familiar with it nor with the precise Tex expansion process, I prefer to ask you experts before I invest heavily in the understanding of this module.

Addition :
Pushing forward the reflection, a consequence would be that from a Latex code I get a Latex code instead of a pdf file for instance. This implies that we use only the first steps of the four TeX processors as described by Veijkhout in "TeX by Topic" : the input processor, the expansion processor (but with a controlled depth of expansion), not the execution processor nor the visual processor. Moreover, there would be need to show the intermediate state, that means a new processor able to show tokens back into readable strings and correct Tex/Latex code that can be processed later.
Unless somebody has already done or seen something like that, I feel that my wish may be unfeasible in the short and middle terms. What is your feeling, should I abandon any hope ?